# Simplest code stopped working after StructureMap upgrade. Is it a bug or configuration should be modified?

Tags: c#, exception, dependency-injection, configuration, structuremap

After **StructureMap** upgraded from 4.0.1.318 to 4.4.1 I am always getting "**No default Instance...**" exception:

```
No default instance or named instance 'Default' for requested plugin type IDataProvider<Data>
1.) Container.GetInstance<IDataProvider<Data>>({System.Guid=b9f61fdb-2755-42b0-8147-7acd57a5aa1b})

at StructureMap.Container.BuildInstanceWithArgs(Type pluginType, Instance defaultInstance, ExplicitArguments args, String requestedName)
at StructureMap.Container.DoGetInstance(Type pluginType, ExplicitArguments args)
at StructureMap.Container.GetInstance[T](ExplicitArguments args)
at StructureMap.ExplicitArgsExpression.GetInstance[T]()
at SmTest.Program.Main() in g:\SmTest\SmTest\Program.cs:line 41
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The code is quite simple:

```
public interface IData
{
}

public class Data : IData
{
}

public interface IDataProvider<TData> where TData : IData
{
    TData Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataProvider : IDataProvider<Data>
{
    public DataProvider(Guid id, Data data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container(_ => _.Scan(x =>
        {
            x.WithDefaultConventions();
            x.AssemblyContainingType<IData>();
            x.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IDataProvider<>));
        }));

        // Exception happens here!
        var instance = container
            .With(Guid.NewGuid())
            .GetInstance<IDataProvider<Data>>();
    }
}
```

The same code perfectly working on 4.0.1.318. How should I change configuration to make it working again?